# Generating test data for an application

Tags: java, xml, database

I have a way to test an application using XML data.

So I want to make a script/app to get data from a table and generate this xml file.

For example I have a table called priorities. The table names are the ones that appear on the xml.

What could a easy way to implement this? This is basically get data from a database and generate some xml data

For example: `select * from priorites`

would return this xml file

```
<Priorities xmlns="model/CMT/Priorities">


 <Priorities xmlns="">
    <TICKET_PRIORITY_CODE>L</TICKET_PRIORITY_CODE>
    <TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION>Low</TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION>
  </Priorities>
  <Priorities xmlns="">
    <TICKET_PRIORITY_CODE>N</TICKET_PRIORITY_CODE>
    <TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION>Normal</TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION>
  </Priorities>
  <Priorities xmlns="">
    <TICKET_PRIORITY_CODE>H</TICKET_PRIORITY_CODE>
    <TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION>High</TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION>
  </Priorities>
  <Priorities xmlns="">
    <TICKET_PRIORITY_CODE>U</TICKET_PRIORITY_CODE>
    <TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION>Unknown</TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION>
  </Priorities>
</Priorities>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JAX-B marshalling.